# Sum from sum in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

```
 SELECT 
f.nummer AS factuur_id,
f.mvoor AS factuur,
f.faktuurnr AS factuur_nr,
f.topdatum AS factuur_datum,
f.vervaldag AS factuur_vervaldatum,
f.totbruto AS factuur_totaal,
SUM(c.totbruto) AS credit_totaal,
SUM(b.bedrag) AS bedrag_totaal,
f.totbruto - (SUM(c.totbruto) + SUM(b.bedrag)) AS SOM

FROM    ((facturen AS f LEFT JOIN creditnota AS c ON f.nummer = c.nummer)

LEFT JOIN betaling1 AS b ON f.nummer = b.factuurnr)

LEFT JOIN klanten AS k ON f.klantnr = k.nr

WHERE f.betaald = 'N'

AND CURDATE() >= DATE_ADD(f.vervaldag, INTERVAL 15 DAY)

GROUP BY f.nummer

HAVING  (factuur_totaal - (SUM(c.totbruto) + SUM(b.bedrag))) > 0 

ORDER BY k.naam
```

And now I want a SUM from the SOM 
Do I need a subquery for this?
And how to I do this?

I know I can just loop it but I want it in 1 query.

mysql, php

Thanks!

Comment: A SUM from the SUM? Can you explain more please?

Comment: sorry I mean a SUM from this line:
f.totbruto - (SUM(c.totbruto) + SUM(b.bedrag)) AS SOM

Comment: Does `SUM(f.totbruto - ( SUM(c.totbruto) + SUM(b.bedrag) )) AS SOM` work?

Comment: Great, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: nope sorry I made a mistake
that does not work
'Invalid use of group function'

Comment: Does the query you posted actually work, and produce what you want it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `SOM` statement in another `SUM()` call:

```
SELECT ...
    SUM(f.totbruto - (SUM(c.totbruto) + SUM(b.bedrag))) AS SOM
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
SELECT SUM(SOM) FROM (
    SELECT 
    f.nummer AS factuur_id,
    f.mvoor AS factuur,
    f.faktuurnr AS factuur_nr,
    f.topdatum AS factuur_datum,
    f.vervaldag AS factuur_vervaldatum,
    f.totbruto AS factuur_totaal,
    SUM(c.totbruto) AS credit_totaal,
    SUM(b.bedrag) AS bedrag_totaal,
    f.totbruto - (SUM(c.totbruto) + SUM(b.bedrag)) AS SOM

FROM    ((facturen AS f LEFT JOIN creditnota AS c ON f.nummer = c.nummer)
LEFT JOIN betaling1 AS b ON f.nummer = b.factuurnr)
LEFT JOIN klanten AS k ON f.klantnr = k.nr
WHERE f.betaald = 'N'
AND CURDATE() >= DATE_ADD(f.vervaldag, INTERVAL 15 DAY)
GROUP BY f.nummer
HAVING  (factuur_totaal - (SUM(c.totbruto) + SUM(b.bedrag))) > 0 
ORDER BY k.naam) AS temp
```

Basically I've just wrapped your query in a `SELECT SUM(<some row>) FROM (<your query>) AS temp`.

Comment: nope I also tried this but I get an sql syntax error 1064 near 'SELECT f.nummer ......

Comment: Try giving the sub_query an aliased name? Just add `AS Data` or something after the last close bracket?

Comment: `SELECT SUM(<some row>) FROM (<your query>) AS Data`